# How does one change the options for Strategy in Passport?

Tags: passport.js, github-api, github-enterprise

Specifically, I'm using `passport-github` to authenticate, but I want to use APIs validated against a GitHub Enterprise server, which is obviously at different URls and not on github.com.

Digging through the source, I can see that the `GitHubStrategy` inherits from `Strategy`, but that appears to be a private object.

The only options I can provide in `GitHubStrategy`'s function params are  *
 *   `clientID`
 *   `clientSecret`
 *   `callbackURL`
 *   `scope`
 *   `userAgent`

But I want to set:
 *   `authorizationURL`
 *   `tokenURL`
 *   `userProfileURL`
 *   `userEmailURL`

However, those can only be set in `Strategy(options, verify)`, which appears to be inaccessible.